How to access new table row if it appears anywhere randomly in Selenium C#?
I am trying to figure out how to find the new table row after a file get uploaded. The issue is that there is no identifier for the new table row as it can appear anywhere in the table. I don't know how to approach this in selenium so is there a way to find the new table row from the file that got uploaded?
I tried checking  the dev tools to see if there was anything that could identify the new table row, but I couldn't really find anything.

Please add HTML code snippet

ask yourself how you identify that row when browsing the site manually.  Then convert that logic to a locator strategy.  (worst case would be if no column holds unique values per row... you'd have to get all rows before, construct an array with row values and #of in case of duplicates, then get all rows after and compare arrays)

There isn't an identifier in the row since it can appear anywhere. It is how the database is set.
